# ValueError when pre-training BERT model using Trainer API

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model, fine-tuning

I'm trying to fine-tune/pre-train an existing BERT model for sentiment analysis by using Trainer API in `transformers` library. My training dataset looks like this:

```
Text                             Sentiment
This was good place                  1
This was bad place                   0
```

My goal is to be able to classify sentiments as positive/negative. And here is my code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from datasets import load_dataset_builder
import datasets
import transformers
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers import Trainer

dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files='my_data.csv', sep=';')
tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
model = transformers.BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased") 
print(dataset)
def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["Text"], examples["Sentiment"], truncation=True)

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
training_args = TrainingArguments("test_trainer")
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model, args=training_args, train_dataset=tokenized_datasets
)
trainer.train()
```

This throws error message:

```
ValueError: text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples).
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer, please have a look and let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

There are several points here to which you need to pay attention in order to have your code working.

First of all, you are working on a sequence classification task, specifically a binary classification, so you need to instantiate your model accordingly:

```
# replace this:
# model = transformers.BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
# by this:
model = transformers.BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=2)
```

You shouldn't provide the labels (`examples["Sentiment"]`) to the tokenizer, as they don't need to be tokenized:

```
# use only the text as input 
# use padding to standardize sequence length
return tokenizer(examples["Text"], truncation=True, padding='max_length')
```

Speaking of labels, your trainer will expect them to be in a column named 'label', so you have to rename your 'Sentiment' accordingly. Note that this method doesn't operate in-place as you could expect, it returns a new dataset that you have to capture.

```
# for example, after you tokenized the dataset:
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.rename_column('Sentiment', 'label')
```

Finally, you need to specify the split of the dataset you actually want to use for training. Here, since you did not split the dataset, it should contain only one: 'train'

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model, 
    args=training_args, 
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets['train'] # here
)
```

That should make your code *work*, but doesn't mean you'll get any interesting result. As you're interested in working with transformers, I strongly recommend you have a look at the [series of notebooks by huggingface](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/notebooks).

Comment: Thank you, this solved the error in OP, but I might need to make new question for next one. Now it says: `The following columns in the training set  don't have a corresponding argument in BertForMaskedLM.forward and have been ignored: Text, Sentiment.`

Comment: This gives the error ´The following columns in the training set  don't have a corresponding argument in BertForSequenceClassification.forward and have been ignored: Text.´ followed by ´ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([8])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([8, 2]))´

Comment: The first message is just a warning, it doesn't prevent your code from running. You can get rid of it by removing the 'Text' column before training, like this ```tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns('Text')```.
It's difficult to guess what is triggering the second message. It may come from the dataset itself. Can you share the file, or an extract from it?

Comment: Here is the CSV file: https://github.com/JereRajala00/training-data. Do you know what that error message means in general?