# Does HuggingFace's Trainer automatically ignore features not required by the model?

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I am a new user of Transformers and I have successfully fine-tuned a BERT model following the tutorial.

However, I have one question about the features I send to the Trainer and those accepted by the BERT model.

Specifically, my original dataset contains two columns named “text” and “label”. After tokenizing the “text”, the dataset object now has three more columns named “input_ids”, “token_type_ids”, and “attention_mask”. I understand that these three columns are required by the BERT model, but I didn’t drop the original “text” column when I fed the dataset to the Trainer API.

So my question is, does BERT automatically ignore non-relevant features? (maybe this is achieved quietly by the Trainer API) Or should I remove these columns, leaving only “input_ids”, “token_type_ids”, and “attention_mask”?

For example, below is my dataset object:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['text', 'label', 'input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask'],
        num_rows: 6851
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['text', 'label', 'input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask'],
        num_rows: 762
    })
})
```

And I fed it and my model to the Trainer:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=data["train"],
    eval_dataset=data["test"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)
```

What happened to the "text" feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, these columns are ignored by the Trainer (see also the comments on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70263251/valueerror-when-pre-training-bert-model-using-trainer-api)).

However, when a column is ignored during training, you should get the following warning message:
`The following columns in the training set don't have a corresponding argument in MyModel.forward and have been ignored: column1, column2. If column1, column2 are not expected by MyModel.forward,  you can safely ignore this message.` (triggered [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/trainer.py#L662) in the code).

Did you disable warnings?